# Start editing in a specific cell in an ExtJs 3.4 grid

Tags: extjs3

In my grid I have added a row editor as plugin (with `new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor()`). I want to set focus on a specific column in a specific record.

This is what I have now:
`editor.startEditing(record);`;

It starts editing and sets focus on the first field, but I want to define a different field. Searching the web I see people having something like: `editor.startEditing(record, column)` or `editor.startEdit(record, column)` the first doesn't seem to work and the latter function does not exist.

The solution could rely in a 'RowEditing' plugin but since ExtJs is new to me I don't understand how to do that.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I am using a grid with a Row Editor in ExtJS 4.0.2 and I programatically add a row and start editing it with this code:

```
var editor = grid.getPlugin('myRowEditor');
grid.getSelectionModel().select(lastRowCounter);   //0 based selector.
editor.startEdit(lastRowCounter,1);  //start editing on Second column.
```

Comment: I made a mistake by assuming it was ExtJs 4, but it is 3.4 actually. Thanks anyway for your answer, it made me realize that. I still don't know how to solve my problem but have to start over looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Before wasting time with programming by trying, I recommend you to read sources.

From RowEditor: `startEditing: function(rowIndex, doFocus)`. So there is a second param, but is not an index.
If you read `onRowDblClick` you will find that they first call `startEditing` disabling focus, and then they handle the cell to focus with `doFocus`.

By the way, `doFocus` depends on a DOM event (where the user clicked). If you don't have such events, you can just take some inspiration from that function: they just call `focus()` on the  column editor, obtained from `ColumnModel#Column#getEditor()`.

Comment: Thanks. In 2016 and your words I ended up using http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/CellEditing.js.html#Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-method-startEditByPosition